# How can I run a single PHP function that gives diffirent results depending on the button value?

Tags: php

First off I do apologize if this has been asked before or something similar. I'm working on this little project for at home and to help me learn a bit on PHP.

What I am trying to achieve here is to have buttons/links that are dynamically generated by reading a directory from one function. This I have accomplished which works as intended for that aspect. Once those are generated and displayed to the user with the webpage. I want to use only one function for all buttons that depending on the button value/name it is passed to the function displays the corresponding directory in HTML.

How can I pass a value from the dynamic buttons to a variable in a different function?

Code I have so far:

**This first function works as intended(it echo's out the specific directory):**

```
function btnSeries(){
    $season = "./SomeDirectory/";
    $files = glob("./Some/Directory_images/*.*");
    for ($i=0,  $f=1; $i<count($files) && $f<count($files); $i++, $f++)
    {
        $num = $files[$i];
            print '<div class="col-md-4">';
            print '<div class="card">';
            print '<img class="card-img-top" src="'.$num.'"alt="Season '.$f.'">';
            print '<div class="card-body">';
            //print '<br>';
            print '<form method="post" action="episodes.php">';
            print '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Season'.$f.'" name="button" />';
            print '</form>';
            //print '<a href="'.$season."Season".$f.'"class="btn btn-primary">Season '.$f.'</a>';
            print '</div>';
            print '</div>';
            print '</div>';
    }
}
```

**The single function that receives the value for Variable from the onclick event**

```
if(array_key_exists('button', $_POST)) { 
    seasonEpisodes();
}

function seasonEpisodes(){
    $buttonValue = "value" //Value passed from button (ie: button name which represent the folder of series)
    $season = "./SomeDirectory/";
    $files = glob("./Series/.$buttonValue/*.*");
    include 'layout/header.php';
    print '<td>';
    print '<p align="center">';
    print '<img border="0" src='.$someVar.' width="370" height="529">';
    print '</p>';
    print '</td>';
        
    for ($i=0,  $f=1; $i<count($files) && $f<count($files); $i++, $f++)
    {
        $num = $files[$i];
            print '<p align="center"><font color="#FFFFFF" size="6">';
            print '<a href=".$season.$file.">';
            print '<font color="#FFFFFF">.$file.</font></a>'
    }
    print '</td>'
    include 'layout/footer.php';
}
```

Thought I would Provide an updated Function with the variable being able to be passed on to the second function thank to RGriffiths. Adding this worked like a charm.

```
function btnSeries(){
    $season = "./SomeDirectory/";
    $files = glob("./Some/Directory_images/*.*");
    for ($i=0,  $f=1; $i<count($files) && $f<count($files); $i++, $f++)
    {
        $num = $files[$i];
            print '<div class="col-md-4">';
            print '<div class="card">';
            print '<img class="card-img-top" src="'.$num.'"alt="Season '.$f.'">';
            print '<div class="card-body">';
            //print '<br>';
            print '<form method="post" action="episodes.php">';
            print '<input type="hidden" value="Season'.$f.'" name="seasonClicked" />';
            print '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Season'.$f.'"/>';
            print '</form>';
            //print '<a href="'.$season."Season".$f.'"class="btn btn-primary">Season '.$f.'</a>';
            print '</div>';
            print '</div>';
            print '</div>';
    }
}
if(array_key_exists('button', $_POST)) { 
    seasonEpisodes();
    $buttonValue = $_POST["seasonClicked"]; //Value passed from button 
    $season = "./SomeDirectory/";
    $files = glob("./Series/$buttonValue/*.*");
    include 'layout/header.php';
    print '<td>';
    print '<p align="center">';
    print '<img border="0" src='.$someVar.' width="370" height="529">';
    print '</p>';
    print '</td>';
        
    for ($i=0,  $f=1; $i<count($files) && $f<count($files); $i++, $f++)
    {
        $num = $files[$i];
            print '<p align="center"><font color="#FFFFFF" size="6">';
            print '<a href=".$season.$file.">';
            print '<font color="#FFFFFF">.$file.</font></a>'
    }
    print '</td>'
    include 'layout/footer.php';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide the input of the season value for each form:

```
print '<form method="post" action="episodes.php">';
    print '<input type="hidden" value="Season'.$f.'" name="seasonClicked" />';
    print '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Season'.$f.'"/>';
print '</form>';
```

Comment: Thank you RGriffiths! When first tried this it didn't work, but I got to looking there was a typo on my end. Passes the value just fine now.